# jquery and javascripts toghether

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have this jquery..

```
<script type='text/javascript'>
$(document).ready(function() {
$('.colnews2').hide();

$("#colnews1 li").click(function() {
    //alert($(this).attr("id"));
    $('.colnews2').hide();
    var value = $(this).attr("id");
    var theDiv = $("#colnews2-" + value);
    theDiv.slideDown();
    colnews1ID=value;
});

});
 </script>
```

and this javascripts..

```
    var pager = new Imtech.Pager();
$(document).onload(function() {
    pager.paragraphsPerPage = 2; // set amount elements per page
    pager.pagingContainer = $('#mainlevel-nav'); // set of main container
    pager.paragraphs = $('div', pager.pagingContainer); // set of required containers
    pager.showPage(1);
});
```

and i need them in the same php.

I tried the following, but does not work.

```
<script type='text/javascript'>
$(document).ready(function() {

var pager = new Imtech.Pager();

    pager.paragraphsPerPage = 2; // set amount elements per page
    pager.pagingContainer = $('#mainlevel-nav'); // set of main container
    pager.paragraphs = $('div', pager.pagingContainer); // set of required containers
    pager.showPage(1);


$('.colnews2').hide();

$("#colnews1 li").click(function() {
    //alert($(this).attr("id"));
    $('.colnews2').hide();
    var value = $(this).attr("id");
    var theDiv = $("#colnews2-" + value);
    theDiv.slideDown();
    colnews1ID=value;
});

});
</script>
```

Comment: Why can't you just use both? Nothing says you can't have multiple listeners for a single page load complete.

Answer (score 0):

I do not see why you cannot keep these in separate files, just change your onload to ready:

```
<script type='text/javascript'>
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('.colnews2').hide();

    $("#colnews1 li").click(function() {
        //alert($(this).attr("id"));
        $('.colnews2').hide();
        var value = $(this).attr("id");
        var theDiv = $("#colnews2-" + value);
        theDiv.slideDown();
        colnews1ID=value;
    });
});
</script>

var pager = new Imtech.Pager();
$(document).ready(function() {
    pager.paragraphsPerPage = 2; // set amount elements per page
    pager.pagingContainer = $('#mainlevel-nav'); // set of main container
    pager.paragraphs = $('div', pager.pagingContainer); // set of required containers
    pager.showPage(1);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

why dont you put both of them in the `onload` event handler.